# Capture logs in AWS Cognito when user changes password, signs out, refreshes token

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cognito

I need to capture logs in Cognito when

1. A user's token is generated/refreshed
2. A user changes password
3. A user signs out

I know the first can be achieved using the userpool trigger. Is there a place in AWS (CloudWatch/elsewhere) where these logs are stored and can be accessed? I see metrics in CloudWatch, but I want logs with user name, time stamp and device.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that first can be achieved using [PreToken Generation Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) . For user **sign in** and **change password**, there are no logs or Lambda triggers currently. You will need to log this information from client side application.